# what sdk I need to code in old java base mobile phones?

Tags: java, sdk

I have a very old mobile phone, it does not have android, its an old LG Crystal and Im afraid it only supports java technology.

How should I proceed to develop a simple app for it? Which SDK or IDE I need to use? Never coded in Java, only C#, think its a nice way to start and give some life to my old phone hehe.

Thanks

Comment: Java Micro Edition (J2ME) will help you for starters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java there is a Micro edition which is for mobiles and other embedded systems.With this you can create mobile apps.You can read about it in wikipedia in the following link. [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition)
You can download this JDK from this [oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/sdk/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnes)